# C malloc and free does not work

Tags: c, pointers, valgrind

I am new to C and I have some troubles with malloc and free. I can not figure it out where is the problem. I have a program with prime.c and main.c

I use malloc allocation for my array and when I call free in main.c valgrind shows me this error

```
==13518==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13518==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==13518== 
==13518== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13518== 
==13518== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==13518== 
==13518== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==13518== Invalid read of size 1
==13518==    at 0x40D2DFB: ____strtol_l_internal (in /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so)
==13518==    by 0x40D2C68: strtol (in /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so)
==13518==    by 0x40CFAFF: atoi (in /usr/lib/libc-2.23.so)
==13518==    by 0x80487B0: main (in /media/test/prime)
==13518==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13518== 
==13518== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

here are my two classes

prime.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prime.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uint64_t* findPrime(uint64_t max ,size_t* primeCount)
{

    int cnt=0;
    uint64_t *array;
    array = (uint64_t *) malloc(max * sizeof(uint64_t));


    if(array ==NULL)
    {

    return (uint64_t*) 1;
    }


for(int i =2; i < max;i++)
    {
    array[i] = i;
    }

for(int i = 2;i <= sqrt(max);i++)
    {

    if(array[i] != 0)
    {

for(int j = (i*i); j< max; j =j+i)
        {
    array[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    }

for(int i =2; i <max; i++)
    {
        if(array[i])
        {
        cnt++;
        }
    }

    *primeCount = cnt;
return array;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prime.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int len = argc-1;
    int limit = atoi(argv[1]);
    int ret =1;
    size_t pc =0; 


    if(len == 1)
    {
    limit = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    else if(len == 2)
    {
    limit = atoi(argv[2]);
    ret = strcmp(argv[1],"-p");

    if(ret != 0)
    {
    printf("Invalid input!\n");
    return 1;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    printf("Wrong number of arguments!!!\n");
    return 1;    
    }

    uint64_t* primes  = findPrime(limit, &pc);
       printf("Total number of primes %zu \n", pc);

    if(ret == 0)
    { 
        for(int i =2; i < limit;i++)
        {
        if(primes[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("primess: %lld \n", primes[i]);
        }    
        }
    }
    free(primes);
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, C does not have classes.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `if(array ==NULL)
    {

    return (uint64_t*) 1;
    }` is fishy...

Comment: @SouravGhosh: That's putting it mildly.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Its not fishy, its almost a whale right there

Comment: valgrind is telling you where the error is. You're calling `atoi` on a NULL pointer. This has nothing to do with malloc or free because you're crashing long before you've had a chance to call malloc. You might want to check argc before you fiddle with argv.

Comment: I think @Art has your answer. You're initializing `limit` before you've checked if there is an `argv[1]`. Fix that and you'll be on to your next bug. Good luck.

Comment: What are the command line arguments ?

Comment: why did you removed the code from your question? It strips the answer you received of the context.

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace in the valgrind output attributes the error to one of the three calls to `atoi()` by `main()`.  The specific problem appears to be that a null pointer was passed to that function.  The argument to each `atoi()` call is an element of the `argv` array, so your (immediate) problem is with program argument handling, not with dynamic memory allocation.

It looks like the problem must be here:

```
int limit = atoi(argv[1]);
```

You perform that `atoi()` call unconditionally, but when `argc` is less than 2, it exhibits undefined behavior.